# NHibernate Query Over to sort IList in Entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I have two entities

```
      public class ProductEntity
        {
         public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
         public virtual string Name { get; set; }
         public virtual IList<PriceScheduleEntity> PriceSchedules { get; set; }  
        }
        public class PriceScheduleEntity
        {
         public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
         public virtual DateTime Date{get;set;}
         public virtual ProductEntity Product { get; set; }
        }
```

One to Many mapping have been done.
One product may have many priceschedules

When i do the query

```
    IList<ProductEntity> entityList = NHSession.QueryOver<ProductEntity>()
            .Where(x => x.Name.IsLike("%" + matchString + "%"))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name).Asc.List();
```

It gives me the priceschedules as they were added.
I want them sorted through the effective date.
Please help me with the query.

Comment: Are you trying to sort `ProductEntity` by `PriceScheduleEntity.Date`?

Comment: Since one `ProductEntity` has many `PriceScheduleEntity`s, which one do you want to sort by?

Comment: for every productentity the list of priceScheduleentity should be sorted according to the date

Answer (score 0):

in mapping (e.g. FLuentNHibernate mapping)

```
HasMany(x => x.PriceSchedules).OrderBy(s => s.Date)
```

you should do an ordered insert in code so it won't break this sorted contract after adding an item in code.